# Streamwriter - Array of strings to .txt file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I've been working on a project and I need to print an array of words to a text file on individual lines with the positon it is in the array. I have used streamwriters in the past so I was planning on using it again for this however I can't seem to get it to write the text file. Below is the code:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    string sentence;
    String[] words;
    int a;
    bool wordAppear;
    string textbox2;
    string path;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sentence = txt1.Text.ToLower();
        words = sentence.Split();
        a = words.Length;
        MessageBox.Show("Number of Words: " + a);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + @"\file1000.txt");
        for (int i=0; i < a; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(words[i] + " " + i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Part of my task involves listing the order that the word first appears so for example if the sentence was 'I have twenty men with twenty hammers' the order would be 1 2 3 4 5 3 6 so if anybody has any ideas on how to do this please could you suggest them

Comment: I think you need to use `using` statement on your `sw`

Comment: You need to add Flush and Close() methods.  The using like Aleks automatically does the Flush() and Close().  The write stream doesn't automatically do Flush() so not all the data gets into the file when you leave out the flush().

Comment: I believe that 'using' is only to stop you having to 'sw.close(); and sw.dispose();' but I may be wrong. Also is the '.Flush()' important because I've never previously used it and on my previous projects it works without it plus there isn't any file being created which seems to be the problem.

Comment: So when you exit the app, there is no file but when you click the button there is no exception raised? Are you sure that code even run?

Comment: Yes it does run as the message box shows and there is no exception

Answer (score 2):

This should work (assuming ASCII strings):

```
var xs = "I have twenty men with twenty hammers".ToLower().Split();
var memo = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (var i = 0; i < xs.Length; i++)
{
    var index = 0;

    if(!memo.TryGetValue(xs[i], out index))
        memo.Add(xs[i], i + 1);
}

using(var sw = new StreamWriter(SOME_PATH));
    foreach(var x in xs)
        sw.WriteLine(x + " " + memo[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to wrap it up with a Close() method and also handle the ...WriteLine() function a bit differently. Hope this helps.

```
    ...
    words = sentence.Split( );
    a = words.Length;
    MessageBox.Show("Number of Words: " + a);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + @"\file1000.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(words[i] + " " + (i + 1).ToString());
    }

    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: better apply `using`. FileHandles are unmanaged resources that better get disposed off properly. Closing alone is not going to cut it.